# Listview is not visible with other elements on top of it

Tags: android, user-interface, android-layout

I'm trying to create UI like the attached image.  My xmal code below.  There is one main issue that I"m running into.  I understand that I can't embed a `listview` within a `scrollview`.  The problem is, because of all the stuff on top of the listview, only a small portion of the listview is shown no matter what kind of height I give the parent linearlayout.

How can I layout my UI so that the listview will be visible and can be scrolled to with other UI elements on top of it?  Any suggestion is apperciated.
Thanks in advance

[image: attached image.]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:minWidth="25px"
android:minHeight="25px"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/bkicon"
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25dp"
    android:minHeight="25dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bkicon"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutButtons">
    <Button
        android:text="Posts"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mybuttonSelected"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/btngohomemb" />
    <Button
        android:text="Chat"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/btngohomemb" />
    <Button
        android:text="Business"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/btnMBRefresh" />
    <Button
        android:text="Resources"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/btnMBNewMessage" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:text=""
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
    android:id="@+id/locHeader" />
<TextView
    android:text=""
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:id="@+id/locBody"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" />
<TextView
    android:text="\nWhat's on your mind?\n"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:id="@+id/lblWhatonyourmind"
    android:background="#000000" />
<ImageView
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_gallery"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView1" />
<EditText
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="8"
    android:minLines="6"
    android:gravity="top|left"
    android:maxLines="10"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/etNewPost" />
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bkicon"
    android:weightSum="3"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayoutButtons">
    <Button
        android:text="Add Pic"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/btnPostPicture" />
    <CheckBox
        android:text=""
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/chbxRestrict" />
    <Button
        android:text="Post"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/mybutton"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:id="@+id/btnPost" />
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:minWidth="25px"
    android:minHeight="25px"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lvPostedMsges" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: This is happening because the heights of the elements above the Listview are taking the minimum space they need and thus leaving the small portion free for the list view, since linear layout stacks elements on after the other giving priority to the previous elements.

So think about redesigning your page in a better way.

Comment: Thanks Nader.  so there is no way to mix static elements with a listview at the bottom?

Comment: you can use a LinearLayout instead of a ListView, and put the view in it programmatically if needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because the heights of the elements above the Listview are taking the minimum space they need and thus leaving the small portion free for the list view, since linear layout stacks elements on after the other giving priority to the previous elements. So think about redesigning your page in a better way.